# python scraping max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website (~3000 pages) once a day. My code for the requests is:

```
#Return soup of page of Carsales ads
def getsoup(pagelimit,offset):
    url = "http://www.carsales.com.au/cars/results?q=%28Service%3D%5BCarsales%5D%26%28%28%28SiloType%3D%5BDemo%20and%20near%20new%20cars%5D%7CSiloType%3D%5BDealer%20used%20cars%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BDemo%20and%20near%20new%20cars%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BPrivate%20seller%20cars%5D%29%29&cpw=1&sortby={0}&limit={1}&offset={2}".format('Price',str(pagelimit),str(offset))
    #Sortby options: LastUpdated,Price,
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib") #"html.parser"
    totalpages = int(soup.find("div",  class_="pagination").text.split(' of ',1)[1].split('\n', 1)[0])
    currentpage = int(soup.find("div",  class_="pagination").text.split('Page ',1)[1].split(' of', 1)[0])   
    return (soup, totalpages, currentpage)

adscrape = []
#Run through all search result pages, appending ads to adscrape    
while currentpage < totalpages:
    soup, totalpages, currentpage = getsoup(pagelimit,offset)
    print 'Page: {0} of {1}. Offset is {2}.'.format(currentpage,totalpages,offset)
    adscrape.extend(getpageads(soup,offset))
    offset = offset+pagelimit
    # sleep(1)
```

I have previously run it successfully with no sleep() function to rate limit. However now I am getting errors midway through execution, it does this whether or not sleep(1) is active in the code or not:

```
...    
Page: 1523 of 2956. Offset is 91320.
Page: 1524 of 2966. Offset is 91380.
Page: 1525 of 2956. Offset is 91440.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Google Drive\pythoning\carsales\carsales_v2.py", line 82, in <module>
    soup, totalpages, currentpage = getsoup(pagelimit,offset)
  File "D:\Google Drive\pythoning\carsales\carsales_v2.py", line 28, in getsoup
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.carsales.com.au', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /cars/results?q=%28Service%3D%5BCarsales%5D%26%28%28%28SiloType%3D%5BDemo%20and%20near%20new%20cars%5D%7CSiloType%3D%5BDealer%20used%20cars%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BDemo%20and%20near%20new%20cars%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BPrivate%20seller%20cars%5D%29%29&cpw=1&sortby=Price&limit=60&offset=91500&user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000001A097710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

I'm assuming this is due to hitting the server with too many requests in a certain time. If so, how can I avoid this without making the script take hours and hours to run? What is the normal practice for scraping websites to counter this issue?

Comment: check out [exponential binary backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) to space out your retries when you are being throttled.

Comment: `getaddrinfo` failure implies general network issues, not rate limiting (which would most likely manifest as a 400/500, connection refused or timeout).

Comment: engineerC - I have tried this both on my own PC and on a VPS so I don't think it would be network issues (not from my end anyway)